# Unfinished upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10 now showing errors

Tags: upgrade, updates, 19.04, 19.10

a somewhat new-ish linux user here. Was using Ubuntu 19.04, software-updater said I could now update to 19.10, so I said okay. Laptop suddenly turned off in the middle of update, I turned it on again and now tried software-updater again. It says that I have an interrupted upgrade (I selected partial upgrade) it wouldn't work (python symlink to /usr/bin/python) tried manually setting it. I did play around with python symlink before because 2.7 or something was installed along with 19.04 and I removed it and pointed the /usr/bin/python to python3 so it would run by default. Wouldn't work so I did try apt install --reinstall python3.

Okay still upgrade wasn't done, so in the meantime I tried a --fix-broken-installation (just trying to throw everything at it I guess) and a apt update and apt upgrade.

Now the output of apt upgrade has sources from .../ubuntu eoan/... so I guess the previous upgrade has set it to that. and now lsb_release -a says 19.10 (after apt upgrade)

so is it now really 19.10? or is this still some partial upgrade (packages upgraded but the rest aren't like the kernel or something) so how can I check for the completeness of the 19.10 upgrade?

Output of **lsb_release -a**; **sudo apt update**; **sudo dist-upgrade --simulate**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease
Hit:7 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:8 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:9 http://ph.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-5.0.0-32 linux-headers-5.0.0-32-generic
  linux-image-5.0.0-32-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-32-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-32-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Inst libdjvulibre-text [3.5.27.1-13] (3.5.27.1-13ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-updates, Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-security [all])
Inst libdjvulibre21 [3.5.27.1-13] (3.5.27.1-13ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-updates, Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-security [amd64])
Conf libdjvulibre-text (3.5.27.1-13ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-updates, Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-security [all])
Conf libdjvulibre21 (3.5.27.1-13ubuntu0.1 Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-updates, Ubuntu:19.10/eoan-security [amd64])
```

EDIT: added outputs according to comment

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade --simulate`. It may be lengthy. It may be possible to fix your system, or it may not. The output will tell. Back up all data that you want to preserve in case a re-install is necessary. Why, exactly, did your laptop "suddenly turn off?" Ubuntu is not designed to run on faulty hardware.

Comment: Do it again without the --simulate flag (meaning: do it for real). Looks like you were fortunate today and there is nothing left to repair - just a couple kernel upgrades.

Comment: Didn't do the sudo dist-upgrade but continued the upgrade with the software updater (GUI) now when I try sudo dist-upgrade it says it doesn't find it, but sudo apt dist-upgrade says nothing is to be updated already.

Is this now okay?